# ld: framework not found GoogleMapsCore clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode9.4

I don't know why I have this error("linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)") on my IOS app.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you import GoogleMapsCode framework?

Comment: Show us your code...

Comment: @aBilal17 GoogleMapsCode doesn't show there

Comment: @Ivan Kaloyanov Code is working well

Comment: @AamirKhan if your code working fine . .. than whats the issue. Just restart your xcode hope this will help you

Answer (score 3):

This may happen because any of the following reasons.

- if you do not import the framework properly.
- if you are opening the **.xcodeproj** instead of **.xcworkspace**
- Check the build settings -> **Build Active Architectures only** is set to No. (Then change it to **YES**)
- Adding the ***other linker flags*** in ***Project*** and not in ***Targets***. So, you move it to ***Targets***, it shouldn't be in ***Project***

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and the problem was that mine Framework folder is not inside the project folder.

Build Settings > Framework Search Paths > enter these 2 lines in the window

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)/../<YOUR_FOLDER_WITH_FRAMEWORKS>
$(inherited)
```